# Выбрать следующий элемент после таргета

Tags: javascript

Есть 2 img в коде

```
<div class="game" onclick="switchSide(event)">
      <div class="slot">
            <img class="back" src="img/suit.png" />
            <img class="front hidden" src="${card.img}" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Первый получаю через event.target, как мне от него же выбрать второй?
Пробовал так

```
const back = event.target;
const front = back.nextSibling;
```

но выходит какая-то шляпа :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Учитесь дебажить код, т.к. ваша переменная `front` возвращает `#text "\n    "` (узел `#text`, который содержит перенос строки).
А всё потому, что [`nextSibling()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) возвращает **узел**, любой.

Решение - использовать [`nextElementSibling()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling), который вернёт следующий **элемент**.

```js
function switchSide(event) {
  const back = event.target;
  const front = back.nextElementSibling;
  
  back.style.color = 'red';
  front.style.color = 'blue';
}
```

```html
<div class="game" onclick="switchSide(event)">
  <div class="slot">
    <img class="back" src="img/suit.png" alt="current"/>
    <img class="front hidden" src="${card.img}" alt="next"/>
  </div>
</div>
```